# Edit react component in google optimize

Tags: reactjs, google-optimize

I have a form with 2 steps. The form has a single auto search field and a submit button for 2 steps.

When I run the A/B test and edit the button text on both steps separately, it is not getting done.

Please let me know if it is possible to edit button text on both steps.